# Count number of files in subfolders in Python

Tags: python

Is there a simple way to count the total number of `pdf` files in a folder that contains a number of other folders among which some contain multiple level subfolders and others just `pdf` files?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26652316/11901732) provides a very good solution to count number of files in each folder on the first subfolder level but not further down to individual `pdf` files.

Comment: pls show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided your pdfs end in the expected file extension, the solution is trivial:

```
import os
my_folder = "./" # your path here
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_folder):
    count += len([fn for fn in files if fn.endswith(".pdf")])
print(count)
```

It is a separate question if you want to determine the filetype by the contents directly; that is a harder problem.

Comment: Hi anon01 thanks for the succinct answer! Could you please add some comments to elaborate this method?

Comment: no need, python has that built in.  Try `help(os.walk)` and scroll to the example at the bottom.  The code should look familiar :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import os
count=0
def new_folder(path,arrs):
    global count
    
    for arr in arrs:
        if os.path.isdir(path+"\\"+arr): #=== Joins the path with the name and check if it is a folder
            try:
                a1=os.listdir(path+"\\"+arr)
                new_folder(path+"\\"+arr,a1) #=== Pass that as a function and iterate over it.

            except PermissionError: #=== Permission denied
                pass
        else:
            if arr.endswith(".pdf"): #=== If it ends with a .pdf extension 
                print(path+"\\"+arr) #=== Print file path
                count+=1 #=== Add 1 to count
    return count

path="C:\\Users\\91996"
arrss=os.listdir(path) #== List all files and directories 
print("PDF Files Found: ",new_folder(path,arrss))
```

Comment: Hi Sujay, yes, thanks for the awesome answer! Do you mind adding some brief comments for learning purpose?

Comment: why use a global counter?